# google customsearch daily quota exceeded

Tags: google-custom-search

In a script I'm using the following url

```
https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?gl=nl&hl=nl&cr=nl&key={API_KEY}&gl=nl&q={QUERY}&rsz=large&language=nl&start=1&cx={CX_KEY}
```

to fetch the 10 results based on a query.

I'm ok with the 100 daily limit but I want to run this script on multiple domains. I can't figure out how to get a 100 daily limit / search engine I create.

It seems the quota is reached as soon as the sum of each search engine requests = 100...

So if I duplicate my script on 100 domains, I'm left with 1 request a day???

Comment: In the mean time you may have found that the 100 request per day is for the JSON/Atom Custom Search API, then it's $5 per 1000 requests (similar pricing as google site search). The ad-supported CSE is free and unlimited! And of course you'd set up an account for customers, but it's likely they already have a google account (webmastertools, analytics, etc). BTW, CSE v1 is no longer supported...

Comment: @yezzz do you have a link for ad-supported CSE?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/overview ... be aware of the JSON api cost, and also the difference between CSE and the (now deprecated)  GSS: https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/4541888?hl=en

Comment: Hi, totally forgot about this... eventually I got it to work ... It appeared the 100 limit is / project. So within 1 account you can create multiple projects (12 max or so but extendable). each project then has its own 100 calls to the API. Although it took me 11 months to respond, luckily I've found the solution sooner ;)